# Neo4J: checking if list elements are featured in matched nodes

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher, py2neo

My Neo4j query is not working - and I can't quite figure out why.

```
match (entry:Entry)
with split("\some space delimited string", " ") as i, 
split("\some space delimited string", " ") as j

where (any (x in entry.X.list where x in i) and any(y in entry.Y.list 
where y in j) and entry.parent="test_1.csv")
return entry
```

The properties of an "Entry" node consist of a X, Y and Z parameters.

I am trying, using py2neo, to pass 2 string representations of lists into the cypher query, filter the nodes that contain the intersection of any element of the 2 lists in certain co-ordinate frames (ie. the X of the entry node has an element from list 'i' AND the Y of the entry node has an element from list 'j') - and then return the entry.

However, when I run the query in the Neo4J browser, it tells me that the variable "entry" was not defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WITH clause is used (among other things) to redefine what variables are in scope. Since you didn't include `entry` in the WITH clause, it dropped out of scope, and so you can't use it past that point, thus the error.

To fix this, simply add `entry` in that WITH clause along with `i` and `j`:

```
...
with entry, split("\some space delimited string", " ") as i, 
split("\some space delimited string", " ") as j
...
```